# PostgreSQL two different ways to generate a UUID: gen_random_uuid vs uuid_generate_v4?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, uuid

What is the difference between the following two functions

- `gen_random_uuid()` provided by [`pgcrypto` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html)
- `uuid_generate_v4()` provided by [`uuid-ossp` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html)

Are they both the same behind the scenes? Any performance impacts on using one?

Comment: good question and welcome to [dba.se]. I would look into it, but I'm going to sleep maybe tomorrow. =)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Are they the same?

No.

The [Postgres documetation for uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/uuid-ossp.html#AEN170626) suggests using `gen_random_uuid()` If you only need randomly-generated (version 4) UUIDs,

The uuid-ossp extension also provides other types of UUID (such as mac-addresses based)

> The difference?

I looked at the source and discovered that

- `uuid_generate_v4()` uses arc4random to determine the random part.
- `gen_random_uuid()` uses fortuna instead.

Other than that they do the same job.

Notes:

- `gen_random_uuid()` from the `pgcrypto` module is now deprecated, because it is natively part of PostgreSQL ([since PostgreSQL version 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/13.0/)).
- `uuid_generate_v4()` still requires the `uuid-ossp` module.

Comment: arc4random vs. fortuna, why should you care? As best I can tell arc4random *could* have some vulnerabilities. Fortuna appears to be more secure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#RC4-based_random_number_generators https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85601/is-arc4random-secure-enough/172905#172905

Comment: About the performance impact: by a simple test (on PG 15.3), it looks like `gen_random_uuid` is more than twice as fast. On an empty `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE uuidv4 (id uuid)`, an `INSERT INTO uuidv4 SELECT gen_func() FROM generate_series(1, 1000000)` took 1 s 192 ms for gen_func = gen_random_uuid, and 2 s 614 ms for uuid_generate_v4.